# SSH Randomly Disconnecting Without Warning

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, authentication

I have been using a certain remote server for the past several weeks without issue, but earlier this week, all of a sudden, it began to deny me entry. Rebooting the server allows me to authenticate once again, but only for a few hours. If I am currently in an ssh session, it says the pipe is broken, and when I next try to log in, it displays a dire warning that the "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED". In the long term, the uptime for this server is important, so I would prefer not to have to restart the computer every time it logs me out (and ideally, it shouldn't log me out at all).

It's worth saying that until this started happening, the server had a fairly weak password, which has since been replaced with a better one. The sysadmin seemed to think that security through obscurity was enough for this machine until this happened. However, I couldn't find any other actual continued evidence of a breach (using `ps aux` and checking crontab), other than the fact that the server keeps kicking me out.

I know many questions on the StackExchange network are fairly similar to this one, but none of the solutions I've read have worked.

Preemptive Edit: I kept getting a notice saying "This looks like spam" upon attempting to post. I have removed the outputs mentioned below, and left the summaries as I had them. When prompted, I'll post them back.

---

**Diagnostic attempt 1:** `ssh -vvv` (clientside)

Summary: I didn't learn much from this output. Maybe someone here will get more out of it. It just looks like I entered the wrong password, which I am very sure is not the case.

**Diagnostic Attempt 2:** `ping` (clientside)

Summary: Someone else with the exact same symptoms as me said that the issue was that there was too much latency on the way to the server. I thought this was unlikely in my case, but it was a lead worth following. I had latency <2ms, consistently.

**Diagnostic Attempt 3:** Checking serverside CPU usage and processes

Summary: The sysadmin was able to give me access to the shell of this server via a web interface, since it's a VM where the web interface counts as physical access or something. I'm not really sure why this shell connects and pure ssh doesn't, but the web interface isn't sufficient for my purposes. Anyway, we both thought that the programs I had written for the server may have overloaded it, but nothing was overutilizing the server's memory or CPU usage.

**Diagnostic Attempt 4:** `cat /var/log/syslog` (serverside)

Summary: I thought the `sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/serveral is already mounted` line was suspicious, but I didn't find any results when searching for that line that seemed like it applied to my situation. I also think I'm probably too deep down the rabbit hole here. When reading this log, you should be aware that the pipe broke at 16:16 on May 9. The output is too large for me to reasonably display here, but this is the tail end of it, from after the server was finished rebooting.

Comment: This sounds like a problem that the sysadmin should be solving.

Comment: Fair enough, but any insight that could help either of us diagnose or solve the issue would be appreciated. It is important that I be able to communicate with the server over SSH without constant unexpected downtime.

Comment: Perhaps this is a conflict of ip addresses.

Comment: It turned out that was the case. A different server on the network didn't have a static IP, and occasionally took the same IP address of this server. Thanks!